# Uncheck radio button if it is not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

The first set of buttons toggle the second set.

However if someone checks rbtn1 and then checks rbtn3 but then changes their mind clicks rbtn2 but leaves rbtn4 blank,  rbtn3 is still clicked even though it isn't visible.  I'm trying to uncheck the second set of ratio buttons if there is a change in the first set but the code I have in the onclick has no effect.  Can code like that be in the onclick?

```
  <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn1" onclick="$('#spanOne').show(); onclick="$('#spanTwo').hide(); 
  $('rbtn3').checked = false; "/>

  <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn2" onclick="$('#spanOne').hide(); onclick="$('#spanTwo').show(); 
  $('rbtn4').checked = false;"/>


<span id = "spanOne"> 
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn3" />
</span>

<span id = "spanTwo"> 
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn4" />
</span>
```

Comment: can you write `onClientClick` instead of `onClick` Method. Also asp.net generates its own id if that is runat="server"

Comment: If you can see the syntax highlighting, you can see your second "`onclick=`" is highlighted green, because it's a part of the string quoted by double quotes. Right after that, the `"` closes the attribute and the rest of the javascript is highlighted wrong. Look up string delimiter and escape string. This then brings up a second problem, you can't have `onclick=` inside your script because it's not javascript but an HTML attribute.

Comment: If you post the RENDERED HTML in a [mcve] we can help you better. You can likely delegate from the container

Answer (score 1):

If you define asp controls it requires runat attribute for that control. If control have runat the id will be generated dynamically . To access that dynamic id you can write "[id$={your acual control name}]" . If you treat the rbtn1,rbtn2 as group its better to add GroupName to select only one out of these two. Finally use the below code as a solution.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn1" GroupName="firstset" Text="rbtn1" onclick="$('#spanOne').show();$('#spanTwo').hide(); $('[id$=rbtn3]').prop( 'checked', false);" runat="server" />

<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn2" GroupName="firstset" Text="rbtn2" onclick="$('#spanOne').hide(); $('#spanTwo').show(); $('[id$=rbtn4]').prop( 'checked', false);" runat="server" />


<span id="spanOne">
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn3" runat="server" Text="rbtn3" />
</span>

<span id="spanTwo">
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn4" Text="rbtn4" runat="server" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please delegate - wrap the radios in a static container.

Also give all the radios the same name or they won't be radios.

```
const rads = $("#staticContainer input[type=radio]"); // or [name=rbtn] if you give them that name
$("#staticContainer").on("click","input[type=radio]",function() {
  $(rads).each(function() {
    if (!$(this).is("visible")) $(this).val("") 
  })
})
```

Comment: I have other radio buttons on the page that have nothing to do with this.  Won't that effect them too?

Comment: Not if you wrap them and/or use the name